# Run a powerscript file through a YAML task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

Do you have some simple working example on how to run a powershell script file in a task inside YAML file. just like this one? Seems that mine is not able to pick up and execute the script since logs are not being printed.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: task 1
    inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      filePath: scripts\sample_pwsh.ps1
      arguments: -Name someName
```

Answer (score 1):

- You are using the correct Syntax of PowerShell@2 Task. Try to confirm your filePath. **filePath should be an absolute path from the root.**
- e.g.,filePath: root/complete/path/scripts/sample_pwsh.ps1
- If this does not work, try checking your ps1 script.